# Why are the banners not showing on mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have testing site with eshop (I don't have permission to backend, just need to use  or .

The website is there -> [Click the link](https://216663.myshoptet.com/)

You can see the blue banner in the middle between the products. I am using  to show the banner on mobile too (by default they are invisible under 767px).

It works (if you use developer tools in Chrome or Mozilla), banners are showing, but if I load the site on mobile, banners are not visible and I don't know why.

Any ideas?

The default code is this:

```
@media (min-width: 767px){.banners-top,.banners-content,.banners-footer{display:block}
{.banners-top,.banners-content,.banners-footer{display: none}
```

I am using this code to show the banners on small screens:

```
@media (min-width: 200px){.banners-top,.banners-content,.banners-footer{display:block}
```

Comment: The display: none rule would do it. You can either change that rule as it occurs or override it.

Answer (score 0):

I already done it. If I inspect the site it says for the banner {display: block}.

On desktop, if I set up 400px, the banner shows up, but if I turn the mobile, it doesnt shop up.

See -> [Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpMJb.jpg)

[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z0lJ.png)